# Повторная инициализация script после ajax загрузки

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Имею страницу, на которой вывожу 2 новости. По нажатию кнопки показать ещё, с помощью ajax подгружаются ещё 2 и т.д.

У каждой новости на `<div class="share"></div>` срабатывает скрипт блока "поделиться" от яндекса. Я написал ещё небольшой скрипт, который после нажатия кнопки "показать ещё", удалил бы уже подключеный share.js и выполнил его ещё раз. Необходимость в этом есть, т.к. на подгруженных ajax новостях кнопки шаринга не инициализируются без перезапуска.

И в целом вся эта конструкция прекрасно работает, но только один раз. Т.е. после второго, третьего и т.д. нажатий перезапуск скрипта не происходит.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как зациклить перезапуск скрипта по клику на кнопку. Спасибо.

Добавлю, что второго и последующих удаленй не происходит(я так думаю), т.к. не к чему привязаться, т.е. изначального id уже нет. А как его добавить к вновь запущенному скрипту я не догадался.

```js
$('button').bind("click", function() {
    $('#ShareScript').remove();
    $.getScript("/sites/js/share.js");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <div class="title">Нвость 1</div>
  <div class="share"></div>
</div>
<div class="news">
  <div class="title">Нвость 2</div>
  <div class="share"></div>
</div>

<script id="ShareScript" src="/sites/js/share.js"></script>

<button>Показать ещё</button>
```

Comment: "удалил бы уже подключеный share.js и выполнил его ещё раз" - не надо. Используйте делегирование при назначении обработчиков событий, и танцы не понадобятся http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за направление, но я не вижу применимость метода .on в моём случае. На примере моих набросков не подскажите?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код, который инициализирует "кнопки шаринга". share.js - это Ваш файл?

Comment: @Igor `var share = Ya.share2('my-share');`

Comment: Из ЯндексApi взял https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/

Comment: попробуйте после догрузки новостей и создания новых элементов DOM вызвать `share.destroy(); share = Ya.share2('my-share');`